# verbatiminput on a file without .txt extention

Tags: verbatim, input, external-files

I'm wanting to include the git hash automatically into a document using verbatiminput. However I seem to be unable to use verbatiminput on a file name does that not end with an extention.

```
\verbatiminput{test2.txt} %Works great
\verbatiminput{test2}     %does not work
```

I don't seem to be getting any error messages it just does not add the data in the file.

I'm new to Latex so I could be missing something straight forward.

Comment: it is system dependent so you may need to show what system you are using but if you got no error it presumably input something, do you have a `test2.tex` in your unput path? the extensionless name also references files with extension `.tex` so that you can go `\input{chapter2}` as well as `\input{chapter2.tex}` the system dependence comes as it is possible that it looks for `test2.tex` before or after it looks for `test2`

Comment: I'm using latexmk from within vimtex on win10. No I do not have a "test2.tex" file just "test2" and "test2.txt". Is there some way to tell it to look for the file without an extention?

Comment: make a small complete document (`\verbatiminput` is not defined by default and more than one definition exists in different packages) and show the log file that you get from the test (which should show the path of the file that it includes) there is no way to refer to `test2` without referring to `test2.tex` so you definitely rely on the path search order (simplest of course is to give the file a different extension, but it should work, given a bit of setup)

Comment: Haven't tried it, but would `test2.` work with a period appended?

Comment: Appending the period worked great thanks Steven B (I would not have thought of it). Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it (if it lets me)